# Taking a limit of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

I want to compute the following limit for the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x)^n}$, where $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x)^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1+nx^2}{x^n+nx^{n-1}+\ldots +\binom{n}{2}x^2+nx+1},$$

where in the second part I used the binomial theorem in the denominator. I think the answer should be the zero function, but I'm having trouble showing that. Could someone guide me? Thank you.

Comment: The limit depends on $x$.

Comment: I just corrected my post, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$,the limit is trivially seen to be $1$.  For $0<x\le 1$, exploiting the binomial theorem, we have

$$0\le \frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x)^n}\le \frac{1+nx^2}{\frac12 n(n-1)x^2}$$

whereupon application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x)^n}=\begin{cases}0&,0<x\le 1\\\\1&,x=0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the inequality go the other way?

Comment: @Ana Yes.  My WiFi connection keeps breaking and I was unable to correct.  Finally, it has been restored.